# kubectl can't pull image from private registry for base images

Tags: kubernetes

i'm trying to deploy an app from local kubernetes cluster that has no internet access but has access to private docker registry.

i've successfully done `kubeadm init` with all the base images in my private docker registry.

now i'm trying to deploy an app with an image in my private docker registry, but the deployment is failing because the pause container can't be started with `no basic auth credentials`.

i've already created seperate docker registry secret with credentials for my private docker registry in the same namespace that i'm deploying my app, and also put the secret name in the deployment.yaml in `imagePullSecrets`.

question is how do i configure my kubernetes cluster to use private registry credentials when pulling base images such as pause?

below is the result of "describe pod" for your reference. i've been struggling with this for several days now and i'm going crazy. what am i doing wrong?

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age               From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               30s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned rul/rul-app-85697f6c6d-6n6td to ubuntuworker1
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  5s (x3 over 30s)  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed pulling image "<my-private-registry>/pause:3.2": Error response from daemon: Head http://<my-private-registry>/v2/pause/manifests/3.2: no basic auth credentials
```

if you need to see my deployment.yaml, here it is.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
        name: rul-server-service
        namespace: rul
spec:
        selector:
                app: rul-server
        ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 3300
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
        name: rul-app
        namespace: rul
spec:
        replicas: 2
        selector:
                matchLabels:
                        app: rul-app
        template:
                metadata:
                        labels:
                                app: rul-app
                spec:
                        imagePullSecrets:
                        - name: rul-regcred
                        containers:
                        - name: rul-client
                          image: <my-private-registry>/<my-image>:<tag>
                          ports:
                                  - containerPort: 3000
                        - name: rul-server
                          image: <my-private-registry>/<my-image>:<tag>
                          ports:
                                  - containerPort: 3300
                        - name: rul-python
                          image: <my-private-registry>/<my-image>:<tag>
                          ports:
                                  - containerPort: 7000
```

and as you can tell from the deployment.yaml above, my private registry credentials are in the secret named "rul-regcred" and i've already checked that credentials are safely stored in the secret by checking it with base64 decode.

Also, i've logged in docker to my private registry on all nodes in the cluster, and have confirmed that the credentials are stored in $HOME/.docker/config.json

Comment: Can you post the command that you use to create the docker secret? No need to show the values, just the command and create secret parameters that you used will do.

Comment: sure. here it is. `kubectl create secret generic rul-regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson -n rul`   and i've looked inside my config.json file to make sure that only credentials in there is the one for my private docker registry. i also made sure that the credentials are correct by checking it with base64 decode. i've also tried `kubectl create secret docker-registry rul-regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email> -n rul` to no avail.

Comment: What is the value of **<your-registry-server>**?

Comment: it's myip:myport, where my private registry is running.

Comment: sorry for confusion. <myip> is the server ip hosting private docker registry, and <myport> is the server port that private docker registry is running on.

Comment: Last question, what is the result when you do `docker push <myip>:<myport>/pause:3.2`, did the push complete successfully?

Comment: yes i've tried both pulling and pushing and both commands have completed successfully